# How to use Drawer customComponent. I think Im doing what docs suggest but doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Im trying to customize the Drawer for my Expo RN App but **after hours and hours of endless trying I decided to just ask for help.**

I see im doing just whats docs and other people around the internet are doing:

> DrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig)

but this in my case, it just does not work. All I see is this big red error: [Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKDBz.png)

**The problem is located in my main navigator:**

```
 const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    pedidosNavigator: { screen: PedidosNavigator },
    menuNavigator: { screen: MenuNavigator },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <PerfilScreen {...props} />,
  }
);
```

If I set it up this way, **it works fine but *without* customization**:

```
const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
      {
        pedidosNavigator: { screen: PedidosNavigator },
        menuNavigator: { screen: MenuNavigator },
      })
```

The problem is when I add this object as the docs suggest:

```
{
  contentComponent: props => <PerfilScreen {...props} />,
}
```

Or even when I try to add a width property:

```
{
 drawerWidth: 300
}
```

What the hell Im doing wrong? Here is my full code

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/components/reducers';

import MenuScreen from './screens/MenuScreen';
import PerfilScreen from './screens/PerfilScreen';
import PedidosNuevosScreen from './screens/PedidosNuevosScreen';
import CreateEditMenuScreen from './screens/CreateEditMenuScreen';
import AcceptDeclineScreen from './screens/AcceptDeclineScreen';
import PedidosEnCursoScreen from './screens/PedidosEnCursoScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  const MenuNavigator = TabNavigator({
      menu: { screen: MenuScreen },
      create: { screen: CreateEditMenuScreen }
      }
  );

  const PedidosNavigator = TabNavigator(
    {
      entrantes: { screen: StackNavigator(
        {
          entrantes: { screen: PedidosNuevosScreen },
          nuevoPedido: { screen: AcceptDeclineScreen }
        }
      ) },
      enCurso: { screen: PedidosEnCursoScreen }
    }
  );

const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    pedidosNavigator: { screen: PedidosNavigator },
    menuNavigator: { screen: MenuNavigator },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <PerfilScreen {...props} />,
  }
);

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MainNavigator />
  </Provider>
);
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After even more hours of looking for an answer, I did find the answer. Drawer Navigator **must** contain aditional properties to work.

If you are like me, and want to customize the drawer you will also have to include this props to your Drawer Navigator:

```
 {
 initialRouteName: 'YourMainRouteAsString',
 contentComponent: YourCustomizedComponent,
 drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
 drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
 drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
```